# storing preferences that survives app uninstall

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a common way (Android API) to store info's (shared preferences) from app that will survive if the app is uninstalled and can be read again when the app is reinstalled ?

Comment: I think its not possible, you have to use other mechanisms like storing data to your server for the user preferences and keep shared preferences and server synced with changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use the "external storage" (don't use  getExternalFilesDir()) use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory():

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use external storage(File) for that But you shouldn't do that, you can not force the users to keep data on their phones without their concern.

Other thoughts on this:

1. You can store the data on a remote server and with authentication to retrieve.
2. Using [Data Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) service

Answer (score 0):

// Sorry if once the app will be removed then the shared preferences file will also be deleted from the app. There is no any way to get the data back after reinstalling the app